# Check if two nested lists are equivalent upon substitution

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics, python-itertools

For some context, I'm trying to enumerate the number of unique situations that can occur when calculating the [Banzhaf power indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banzhaf_power_index) for four players, when there is no dictator and there are either four or five winning coalitions.

I am using the following code to generate a set of lists that I want to iterate over.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(map(list, combinations(s, r)) for r in range(2, len(s)+1))

def superpowerset(iterable):
    s = powerset(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(map(list, combinations(s, r)) for r in range(4, 6))

set_of_lists = superpowerset([1,2,3,4])
```

However, two lists in this set shouldn't be considered unique if they are equivalent under remapping.

Using the following list as an example:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 4]]
```

If each element `2` is renamed to `3` and vice-versa, we would get:

```
[[1, 3], [1, 2], [3, 2], [1, 3, 4]]
```

The order in each sub-list is unimportant, and the order of the sub-lists is also un-important. Thus, the swapped list can be rewritten as:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3, 4]]
```

There are 4 values, so there are P(4,4)=24 possible remappings that could occur (including the trivial mapping).

Is there any way to check this easily? Or, even better, is there are way to avoid generating these lists to begin with?

I'm not even sure how I would go about transforming the first list into the second list (but could brute force it from there). Also, I'm not restricted to data type (to a certain extent) and using `frozenset` would be fine.

**Edit:** The solution offered by tobias_k answers the "checking" question but, as noted in the comments, I think I have the wrong approach to this problem.

Comment: I think you could try to find a "normalized" form for each set, and then put all those into a set. Of course, the tricky bit is making the normalized form unique. You could, e.g. sort the numbers in the set and make the most frequent number 1, the next 2, and so on, and use some similar metrics for breaking ties.

Comment: Whats on the desired lists? Are those the winning coalitions or what?

Comment: You should use `set` objects instead of `list` objects if you want to compare lists regardless of ordering. It's also possible to have a set of sets.

Comment: @TonyBabarino Yes, the lists contain the winning coalitions;

tobias_k - looking into that approach;

spiffman - you can't put a set into a set (unhashable), you need to use `frozenset`

Comment: You probably also want to avoid generating sets like `[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]]` that are not upward-closed (`[[1, 2, 3]]` and `[[1, 2, 4]]` are missing)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Jeez, definitely, I completed missed that.

Comment: Also, either a set or its complement should be winning, no?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't believe; in the set-up [6; 3, 2, 1, 1], the coalition (1,2) has 3+2=5 votes and the coalition (3,4) has 1+1=2 votes, both of which are short of the 6 required votes. The winning coalitions are (1,2,3), (1,2,4), and (1,2,3,4). This does bring up an obvious point that I missed, which is that (1,2,3,4) always needs to be a winning coalition and the goal is to enumerate what might be called the "subtraction chains" of this set.

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that codegolf would gobble up. The simple task of de-golfing some pyth stands between you and the solution you need :)

Comment: @HumphreyTriscuit I like the ingenuity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably no complete solution yet, but it might show you a direction to investigate further.

You could map each element to some characteristics concerning the "topology", how it is "connected" with other elements. You have to be careful not to take the ordering in the sets into account, or -- obviously -- the element itself. You could, for example, consider how often the element appears, in what sized groups it appears, and something like this. Combine those metrics to a key function, sort the elements by that key, and assign them new names in that order.

```
def normalize(lists):
    items = set(x for y in lists for x in y)
    counter = itertools.count()
    sorter = lambda x: sorted(len(y) for y in lists if x in y)
    mapping = {k: next(counter) for k in sorted(items, key=sorter)}
    return tuple(sorted(tuple(sorted(mapping[x] for x in y)) for y in lists))
```

This maps your two example lists to the same "normalized" list:

```
>>> normalize([[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 4]])
((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3))
>>> normalize([[1, 3], [1, 2], [3, 2], [1, 3, 4]])
((0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3))
```

When applied to all the lists, it gets the count down from 330 to 36. I don't know if this is minimal, but it looks like a good start.

```
>>> normalized = set(map(normalize, set_of_lists))
>>> len(normalized)
36
```

Comment: It's not minimal; this problem is graph-isomorphism-hard.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Do you know what would be the minimal number?

Comment: Well, it might be in this special case, but not in general.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Do you have an example of two "equivalent" lists that will not normalize to the same value? If not, is this set only minimal because the lists are very ordered to begin with?

Comment: @JaredGoguen I only know that (i) there's a reduction from graph isomorphism via a reduction where each edge gives rise to a coalition on the vertices that are not its endpoints (ii) this answer will not solve graph isomorphism.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049630/efficiently-generating-subtraction-chains) about this problem using a different approach per one of your comments. If you have a minute, would you mind checking it out? I have a bad feeling that I might be trying to solve an unsolvable problem and it would be lovely to verify that sooner rather than later.