# Efficiently generating "subtraction chains"

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, combinatorics

I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047008/check-if-two-nested-lists-are-equivalent-upon-substitution) earlier if you want some context. It appears that I was on the wrong path with that approach.

[Addition chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain) can be used to minimize the number of multiplications needed to exponentiate a number. For example, a<sup>7</sup> requires four multiplications. Two to compute a<sup>2</sup>=a×a and a<sup>4</sup>=a<sup>2</sup>×a<sup>2</sup>, and another two to compute a<sup>7</sup>=a<sup>4</sup>×a<sup>2</sup>×a.

Similarly, I'm trying to generate all of the possible "subtraction chains" for a set of numbers. For example, given the set of numbers `{1, 2, 3}`, I'm trying to generate the following permutations.

```
{1, 2, 3}

{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {2}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2}

{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {3}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1}, {3}

{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2}
{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {3}
{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2}, {3}

{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1}, {2}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1}, {3}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2}, {3}
{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1}, {2}, {3}

# and so on...
```

Where each element in the permutation (besides `{1, 2, 3}`) can be found by removing a single element from another set in the permutation.

For example, the permutation `{1, 2, 3}, {1}` is invalid because `{1}` can not be constructed by removing a single element from `{1, 2, 3}`.

Is there a known algorithm to find this subset of the power set of a power set? My implementation will be in Python, but the question is language agnostic. Also, I don't actually want the permutations which contain a set with a single element (e.g. `{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}`) because they corresponds to a "dictator" case which is not of interest.

Comment: I don't think that an algorithm to generate all those lists of sets would be too difficult to implement, but somehow I fail to see both the connection to addition chains and to your previous question. By your earlier question, shouldn't `{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}`, `{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}`, and `{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}` all be considered equivalent

Comment: @tobias_k You're correct, I don't think I'm going to have time to update the question today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm to generate all those lists as you describe it could work as follows: For each set in the current list, create a copy, remove one element, add it to the list, and call the algorithm recursively. You also have to make sure not to generate duplicates, which could by done by ensuring that the new list is "smaller" (by length or pairwise comparison of the (sorted) elements) than the previous one.

Here's an implementation in Python, as a generator function, without much optimization. This seems to work pretty well now, generating all the subsets without any duplicates.

```py
def generate_sets(sets, min_num=2):
    yield sets
    added = set() # new sets we already generated in this iteration
    for set_ in sets:
        # only if the current set has the right length
        if min_num < len(set_) <= len(sets[-1]) + 1:
            for x in set_:
                # remove each element in turn (frozenset so we can put in into added)
                new = set_.difference({x})
                # prevent same subset being reachable form multiple sets
                frozen = frozenset(new)
                if frozen not in added:
                    added.add(frozen)
                    # recurse only if current element is "smaller" than last
                    if (len(new), sorted(new)) < (len(sets[-1]), sorted(sets[-1])):
                        for result in generate_sets(sets + [new], min_num):
                            yield result
```

For `generate_sets([{1,2,3}], min_num=2)` this generates the following lists:

```py
[{1, 2, 3}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}]
[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]
```

For `generate_sets([{1,2,3}], 1)`, a total of 45 lists of sets are generated.

However, I fail to see the connection to your previous question: Shouldn't `{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}`, `{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}`, and `{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}` all be considered equivalent?

Comment: Yes, they should be, my brain was fried by the end of yesterday. I can combine the solutions from the two questions to get what I need though. (Although, it would be interesting to investigate a more efficient solution.)

Comment: It looks like I've been trying to solve the wrong problem in various different way. Hopefully, the actual problem (and it's solution) are [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54621/enumeration-of-winning-coalations) if you're curious.